# Django sending gmail failed

Tags: django, gmail

I've configured gmail in settings file as following:

```
#gmail_send/settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'yoorusername@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'key' #past the key or password app here
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'default from email'
```

I've turned on less secure app access from google but it's still not working

Here's the error :

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /register
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError n6sm1130142pgm.79 - gsmtp', '"default from email"')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused
Exception Value:    
(530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError n6sm1130142pgm.79 - gsmtp', '"default from email"')
```

Comment: check your email and password to see if it's correct, also set value for your default_from_email https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-from-email

Comment: also go to the url it show to see what else you missing, https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=WantAuthError probably also needed to `allow sign in from less secure app option` too